# Is extending taskbar across two monitors possible?

Tags: windows-7

Is there any freeware available for extending my taskbar. I am using windows 7.
I dont want to purchase or use trial versions.
Please suggest me some good tool.

Comment: The simplest way upgrade to Windows 8 this is supported out of the box in windows 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just been down this road. I wasn't able to find any free software to do this in a nice enough fashion. I am currently using Actual Multi Monitors. The software comes as a trial version which, once expires, loses some features but you can still use it.

Since I am still in trial I don't know what you lose, but as long as the taskbar is extended I don't really mind.